# How get response from express server for ajax query in nuxtjs

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm want to get data from the node/express server after send ajax query from any page of the nuxtjs app.
Usually, for getting and sending ajax query in PHP server, I'm do like this $_GET['var']; echo json_encode('Server got data');
Now I want to use node server express for saving data in mongodb.
When I trying to send a query, response return full code of file test.js.

File index.vue

```
 methods: {
   onServer() {
     this.$axios.get('/server/test').then(res => {
       console.log('res', res.data)
    })
  }
 }
```

File test.js

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
   console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

File server/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()


// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  } else {
    await nuxt.ready()
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

I'm a new user node, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you are targeting "test.js" in your axios url. This is why it responds with the file rather than what the get route should respond with.

So try with:

`this.$axios.get('http://nuxt-profi/server/test').then(...`

and see what you get. You should also be able to access that in the browser, just go to your url `http://nuxt-profi/server/test` and it should show your "Hello World" reponse.

However I can't be sure how you have set all this up. Are you running this as development? In which case maybe you should access it as `http://localhost:3000/server/test` but maybe you have virtual hosts configured like this. Also, is this a separate backend api or are you trying this as server middleware?

If this doesn't help please give us more info about your project setup and we'll go from there.

Comment: Thank for response. I want to use MongoDB. I want to send post ajax requests to the test.js page and implement CRUD in the database there. I plan to use middleware in order to check sessions before the page is loaded into the browser.

Comment: When I send a query with url like that  this.$axios.get('/server/test').then(res => {
        console.log('res', res.data)
      })
I'm getting error " GET http://localhost:3000/php/test 404 (Not Found)"